# PhpCAS redirection loop on iframe

Tags: php, redirect, iframe, cas, phpcas

I have a request that authenticate with phpCAS and works fine when accessing from url directly (copy past url on browser).

But When i use the same url in Iframe src or in button href i got infinite redirection loop.

any ideas ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am using cakephp and the problème was that the security module checks the referer and inset the session if it's not from the same host so i get disconnected and reconnected again by cas and home page redirection.

The solution was using custom session handler for cakephp and ignore referer check.

Answer (score 1):

because when you protect a page using CAS then CAS redirects you to the same url(i.e back url)
after authentication so when you are visiting your page then your iframe section sending request to the CAS and it redirects to your main page and then again iframe sends request to the CAS that's why it's getting into infinite loop. 
for more information about how CAS works you can follow [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS&ei=gNrbUcDnIY-rrAff44GwDg&usg=AFQjCNEanv4sXDSygTlEw7rdDJu_qO1f0g&sig2=eU1E00MpFsXnpMFvnLIvjw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk)